# Go through for loop sorting names in hex value, not ascii

Tags: bash, hex

I have this:

```
for j in $i/*.ext ; do 
    #extra code         
done
```

I can go through all the files in directory $i that end in .ext.
The files are processed according to ascii order. 000001.ext would come before 000002.ext - good.
But, the problem, my files have hexadecimal names. I want 00000c.ext to come before 000060.ext - and I want to keep the filenames the same.

Is there a way to have the functionality of a for loop, but sort the 'incoming' filenames in hexadecimal order?

Update - I get this output when I echo $j, I need c before 60.

```
00000004.ext
00000005.ext
000000060.ext
0000000c.ext
```

Comment: 00000c.ext comes before 000060.ext.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't, my output says different and numbers come before letters - unless I am missing something?...

Comment: Locale? Try setting `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: I added that in my bash script, it seemed to have made no difference, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add zeroes to the start of the number to make normal sorting work:

```
ls | perl -lne 'chomp; $old = $_; s/^/0/ while 30 > length; print "$_\t$old"' \
   | sort | cut -f2 \
   | while read j ; do
    ...
done
```

This won't work if your filenames contain newlines or tabs.

If you want to be able to specify a wildcard mask, you can use something like the following:

```
ls path/*.out \
    | perl -lne 'chomp;
                 $old = $_;
                 s=/([0-9a-f]+)[^/]*$="/" . (0 x (30 - length $1)) . $1=e;
                 print "$_\t$old"' \
    | sort | cut -f2 \
    | while read j ; do 
          ...
      done
```

Comment: I tested this and the output was correct (not like the output in my question). Thanks! But my filenames already have zeros at the front of the number, I don't understand why/how this works.
-And how can I specify the input folder and extension like in my question?

Comment: The problem is the numbers must be of the same length. The code adds zeroes to make the filename 30 characters long.

Comment: Sure that makes sense, thank you for explaining it, I did not realize that was the problem - yes if they were the same length I now see that it would work. Thanks choroba for updating with the wildcard mask :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make each number have the same length (e.g. 8 characters) then add 0x to the front your can tell `sort` to do it for you.

Change:

```
00000004.ext
00000005.ext
000000060.ext
0000000c.ext
```

To

```
0x00000004.ext
0x00000005.ext
0x00000060.ext
0x0000000c.ext
```

Then `ls -1 | sort -n` will give you what you want:

```
0x00000004.ext
0x00000005.ext
0x0000000c.ext
0x00000060.ext
```

`-n` tells `sort` to do a numeric sort.

In the end you need to put the string into a known numeric format in order to be able to sort them numerically.

xt

Comment: Although I said I didn't want to rename my files, although I could rename them and after processing simply remove the 0x. The end result it what I really want, so thank you.